# Is a "2 GHz Intel Core Duo" really the same as a "2 GHz Intel Core ***2*** Duo"

Tags: cpu, macos

I'm trying to get [Sling TV](https://www.sling.com/) set up on an older iMac.  It has

- 10.6 (the minimum required OS),
- 2.5 GB RAM (~2.5 times the required memory), and
- a 2 GHz Intel Core ***2*** Duo.

However, the Sling TV web site claims you need a "2 GHz Intel Core Duo".  I wasn't aware that there was such a thing, but [Googling for the difference between them](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=2+GHz+Intel+Core+Duo+versus+2+GHz+Intel+Core+2+Duo&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) turned up nothing apparently useful, and even [Googling for "2 GHz Intel Core Duo" turned up very little—most results refer to the 2 GHz Intel Core ***2*** Duo](http://www.google.com/search?q=2+GHz+Intel+Core+Duo&client=safari&rls=en&oe=UTF-8&oq=2+GHz+Intel+Core+Duo&gs_l=heirloom-serp.3...0.0.0.82382.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1ac..34.heirloom-serp..0.0.0.VtIqeTj3dRg).  HOWEVER there is [a page from Intel which mentions "2 GHz Intel Core Duo"](http://ark.intel.com/products/27236/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2500-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-667-MHz-FSB).  Is this a different CPU, or just another way of referring to the 2 GHz Intel Core ***2*** Duo?

If they are different CPUs, can I assume the Core 2 came later, and therefore I have a newer CPU than Sling requires?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Core 2 Duo and Core Duo are different and the Core 2 Duo came later so your iMac should support any software that requires at least a Core Duo.

You can tell because the Early 2006 MacBook Pro used the Core Duo while every MacBook Pro after that until 2010 used a Core 2 Duo. This isn't definitive in proving that the Core 2 came after the Core, but Apple's not going to continually downgrade the processor in its top-of-the-line laptop year after year, plus the "2" usually denotes a successor anyway.

Answer (score 1):

They are different processors.

The Core Duo was released earlier in 2006.
The Core 2 Duo was released mid 2006.

For specific dates, and more info on the processors, this Wiki page is a good reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_Duo